# Showing data for a chat with another user

Tags: php, mvc, laravel, repository

I have a get route to show the data for a chat with another user. If an existing chat exists I want to return that, otherwise create a new chat and return it.

```
/chat/user/{contra_user_id}
```

Should my Service or my repository be adding chat members to the chat? Currently I have my service creating each member.

```
class ChatService
{
    private $chatRepository;

    public function __construct(ChatRepository $chatRepository)
    {
        $this->chatRepository = $chatRepository;
    }

    public function findByUsers(User $user, User $contraUser) : Collection
    {
        $chat = $this->chatRepository->findByUsers($user, $contraUser);
        if ($chat = $chat->first()) {
            return $chat;
        }

        $chat = $this->chatRepository->create();
        $member = $this->chatMemberRepository->create($chat, $user);
        $contraMember = $this->chatMemberRepository->create($chat, $user);
        $returnChat = $this->chatRepository->find($chat->id);

        return $returnChat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the functionality in to 2 seperate methods to make it more reusable. Here, `findChatByUsers` could return a collection or null, so the type hint was removed.

```
public function findChatByUsers(User $user, User $contraUser)
{
    $chat = $this->chatRepository
        ->findByUsers($user, $contraUser)
        ->first();

    return $chat;
}

public function getChat(User $user, User $contraUser) : Collection
{
    $chat = $this->findChatByUsers($user, $contraUser);

    // If chat is not available, create new chat
    if (!$chat) {
        $chat = $this->chatRepository->create();
        $member = $this->chatMemberRepository->create($chat, $user);
        $contraMember = $this->chatMemberRepository->create($chat, $user);
        $chat = $this->chatRepository->find($chat->id);
    }

    return $chat;
}
```